# How to write Expectations with ScalaMock?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalamock

This question seems pretty obvious I know, but i've tried everything that is written on the [documentation](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/sharing-scalatest/) and I cant't mock a single method on any classes.

For this test, I am using scalaMock 3 for Scala 2.10 and ScalaTest 2

**DateServiceTest.scala**

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class DateServiceTest extends FunSuite with MockFactory{
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("local")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  implicit val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)

  val m = mock[DateService]
  (m.getDate _).expects().returning(Some(new DateTime)) // Error here
}
```

**DateService.scala**

```
class DateService extends Serializable {

  def getDate(implicit sqlc: SQLContext): Option[DateTime] = {
    Some(new DateTime(loadDateFromDatabase(sqlc)))
  }
}
```

This seems pretty simple for me, but the expectation is Throwing me this error

```
type mismatch; found : Option[org.joda.time.DateTime] required: ? ⇒ ?
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there another way to set the expectations of a method ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDate` method expects a `SQLContext` - try adding a [wildcard (`*`)](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/matching/) or pass the particular `sqlc`:

```
(m.getDate _).expects(*).returning(Some(new DateTime))
// Or, alternatively
(m.getDate _).expects(sqlc).returning(Some(new DateTime))
```